# Parallax image jump

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I used a tutorial on making the Parallax effect for a background image. On the initial scroll the image jumps about halfway down the container div. I think there is an issue with the background position starting to high. I'm not quite sure where to adjust the code for the best results. Can someone clarify this for me?

Here is the Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1og1L34j/

Looking over the code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id = "why" class="plate"></div>
<div id = "how" class = "plate"></div>
<div id = "what" class = "plate"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.plate{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#why{
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: url("/assets/image/rembck.jpg") ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #080808;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var velocity = 0.5;

function update(){
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#why').each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        // subtract some from the height b/c of the padding
        var height = $element.height()-18;
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '50% ' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) +  'px');
    });
};

$(window).bind('scroll', update);
```

Comment: I've used [**this**](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js) for `parallax` effect, try this, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: This was one of the first plugins i used that I could not get to function. I used the same setup as above and called the function manually in java..$('#why').parallax({imageSrc: '/assets/image/rembck.jpg'}); but no effect.

Comment: can you show me how you set it up?

Comment: The $('#why').each makes no sense, since there is only one '#why' element. Also, the final value for the backgroundPosition you are trying to calculate over there will look something like '50%100px'... 
If you'll provide an updated JsFiddle it will help us help you :-)

Comment: I added the jsfiddle to the question.